# Split list with both negative and positive number into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to split a list of strings into a dict some of these strings end up been duplicate keys after they are split, my end goal is to split the list then sum up the values for each key. I have the following code that works, however I receive a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). when the list contains a negative integer. How would I go about fixing this.

```
v=["a:1", "b:3", "c:5","c:3"]
list_of_str  = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace(":", ''), v))
list_of_str

from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_of_str:
    my_dict[k].append(v)
my_dict

defaultdict(list, {'a': ['1'], 'b': ['3'], 'c': ['5', '3']})
```

---

Result with negative value in the list

```
v=["a:1", "b:3", "c:5","c:-3"]
list_of_str  = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace(":", ''), v))
list_of_str
​
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_of_str:
    my_dict[k].append(v)
my_dict

ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-7a8d435becbb> in <module>
      5 from collections import defaultdict
      6 my_dict = defaultdict(list)
----> 7 for k, v in list_of_str:
      8     my_dict[k].append(v)
      9 my_dict

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The result I am going for:
defaultdict(list, {'a': ['1'], 'b': ['3'], 'c': ['5', '3']})
a:1,b:3,c:8
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop where you construct the dictionary you are iterating through elements of `list_of_str`. Each of these elements is a string, and by doing `for k, v in ...` you're asking for the first two characters of that string.

It so happens that in your first example each string ends up with just two characters. However when you have a negative number, you suddenly have three values instead, and you're asking for only two (i.e. you actually have `'c'`, `'-'`, and `'3'`).

You can simplify your problem using something more memorable instead of an empty string when substituting `':'`:

```
list_of_str  = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace(":", ','), v))
```

So that you can than split whatever happens to be the key-value pair in the loop,

```
for el in list_of_str:
   key, value = el.split(',')
   my_dict[key].append(value)
```

This, however, is redundant and a better way would be to skip the replace altogether and split by `':'` right in the loop,

```
for el in v:
    key, value = el.split(':')
    my_dict[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop on your list of strings and try to extract two values each string is treated as an interable with each character being a value of the iterable.

So when you're doing:

```py
k, v = 'b3'
# k = 'b', v = '3'
```

But when you're doing:

```py
k, v = 'c-3'
# k = 'c', 'v' = '-'
```

In the above example the string still has a character left that's why you get
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` the code expected 2 values but you provided 3.

You could do:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

v = ['a:1', 'b:3', 'c:5', 'c:3', 'd:-4']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for str in v:
    key, value = str.split(':')
    my_dict[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a variant of @Speedlulu implementation

sorry, I haven't enough reputation to leave comment(

```
data = ['a:1', 'b:3', 'c:5', 'c:3']
result = {}
for item in data:
    k, v = item.split(':', 1)
    result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + int(v)
```

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = ['a:1', 'b:3', 'c:5', 'c:3']
result = defaultdict(int)
for item in data:
    k, v = item.split(':')
    result[k] += int(v)
```

> result == {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 8}

Comment: Hey @romtu, I find that my answers are received better when I include an explanation of the trade offs between my solution and another. This would help future users who come across your answer decide which solution may work best for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

one-line solution)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = ['a:1', 'b:3', 'c:5', 'c:3']
result = {k: sum(map(int, map(itemgetter(1), g))) for k, g in groupby((v.split(':', 1) for v in sorted(data)), key=itemgetter(0))}
assert result, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 8}
```